# Where are react-dnd connectors used

Tags: reactjs, react-dnd

I'm reading `react-dnd` docs. I cannot understand what is this `connectDropTarget` used for (https://react-dnd.github.io/react-dnd/docs/overview#connectors):

[image]

Is this an obsolete way of connecting React elements to the DND system, that has been replaced with second item of `useDrag` and `useDrop` hooks (the one that gets attached to ref, check example below), or where is this used?

Example:

```
const [collectedProps, drop] = useDrop(() => ({
    accept
}));

return <div ref={drop}>Drop Target</div>;
```